# How to write complexity classes in LaTeX?

Tags: formatting

I would like to write the complexity classes P, NP, NP-complete and NP-hard in LaTex with the mathematical format as follows:

[image: Desired style]

Comment: There is no standard font for this, they can be roman; the picture you post is some `\mathcal`.  See the [comprehensive list of LaTeX symbols](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive) to find which one is closest.

Comment: I'll have a look, thanks.

Comment: That answer allow me to find what I was looking for but it is not actually the same. Anyway, many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is:

```
$\mathcal{N}$   
$\mathcal{NP}$
$\mathcal{NP}$-complete
$\mathcal{NP}$-full
```